# Dart File.writeAsString() method does not write to file if await is not done immediately

Tags: dart

I have the following Dart code that doesn't behave as I expected:

```
final File file = File("result.csv");

Future send(String message) async {
  try {
    await file.writeAsString(message + '\n',
        mode: FileMode.append, flush: true);
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error: $e");
  }
  return await file.length();
}

main() async {
  final futures = <Future>[];
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    futures.add(send("$i"));
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    print(await futures[i]);
  }
}
```

I expected the file to be written as soon as each call to `await futures[i]` in the second loop returned. However this does not seem to be happening.

The file should contain one line for each index from 0 to 99. But it contains a line with `99` followed by an empty line. And the print calls in the second loop always print the same file length, `3`.

The event loop seems to be somehow merging the calls and only actually executing the last call, even though I still get 100 different futures that I await in the second loop.

Why is this happening and how can I allow the futures to run without awaiting them immediately (I really need to await only later, when all of the calls to `send` have been made)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  futures.add(send("$i"));
}
```

multiple `send` are immediately invoked and each one concurrently open and write a string in the file: you have a race condition and at the ends it happens that only one message it is written to the file.

## Use a list of functions that return a future

With a closure it is possible to implement a sequenzialized version for file access that avoid the race condition.

Instead of creating a list of futures, create a list of functions that returns a future:
The shared file resource is accessed sequentially if you call and await such functions in a loop:

```
import 'dart:io';

final File file = File("result.csv");

typedef Future SendFunction();

Future send(String message) async {
  try {
    await file.writeAsString(message + '\n',
        mode: FileMode.append, flush: true);
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error: $e");
  }
  var l = await file.length();
  return l;
}

main() async {

  final futures = List<SendFunction>();
  //final futures = <Future>[];

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    //futures.add(send("$i"));
    futures.add(() => send("$i"));
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    print(await futures[i]());
    //print(await futures[i]);
  }
}
```

## synchronized package

[synchronized](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/synchronized) offers lock mechanism to prevent concurrent access to asynchronous code.

In this case it may be used to avoid concurrent access to `result.csv` file:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:synchronized/synchronized.dart';

final File file = File("result.csv");
final lock = new Lock();

Future send(String message) async {
  try {
    await file.writeAsString(message + '\n',
        mode: FileMode.append, flush: true);
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error: $e");
  }
  return await file.length();
}

main() async {
  final futures = <Future>[];
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    futures.add(lock.synchronized(() => send("$i")));
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    print(await futures[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that it was possible to have synchronization issues like this in Dart because user code can't create Threads (in the absence of isolates). I suppose this is only a problem because `File.writeAsString()` itself is not written in Dart?

Comment: I can't really speak about dart internals, but I think no.
    This behavior is related to the fact that concurrently calling `send` without
    waiting for completion (`futures.add(send("$i"))`) direct the 
    execution of all `send` as soon as possible and concurrently, without file access synchronization.

Comment: synchronization should not be required as the file system itself takes care of that as far as I know. All I would expect is out-of-order writes which is ok in my case.

Comment: I've created a bug and looks like the Dart team thinks it's possible to use an atomic version of append internally, which would fix this problem: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36087